# undo vc-annotate-revision-previous-to-line

Tags: git, version-control

When I've launched `vc-annotate` and then type `a` (`vc-annotate-revision-previous-to-line`), emacs will show me the revision before the one on the current line.

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Old-Revisions.html):

> a
>
> Annotate the revision before the one indicated by the current line.
>   This is useful to see the state the file was in before the change on
>   the current line was made.

After doing this, I now want to go back to the previous revision of the file that I was viewing before I pressed `a`. How can I do this?

If emacs `vc-annotate` doesn't support it natively, are there any packages that can accomplish this? Or how would I go about coding this on my own? I imagine I could just use some sort of stack to store all the revisions visited in the current vc-annotate session, and then pop one off using an undo command.

I am using git, so would even be interested in an answer that applies only to git.

Comment: Using a stack seems like the best approach to me. Store the current revision in `vc-annotate-warp-revision`, and create a command that would pop the value off the stack and go to the top of what remains. Something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an attempt at this. It uses an advise function on vc-annotate (maybe there's a better way, but I couldn't find one) to log the revisions annotated, storing then in stacks, one for each file annotated.

It then adds a function vc-annotate-previous-annotation to redisplay the last annotated revision of the file currently being annotated.

```
;;  A hash table mapping from file names to stacks of vc-annotate calls
(defvar vc-annotate-call-stacks (make-hash-table :test 'equal))

;; Define a structure type to store the details needed to redisplay a revision
;; rev: the revision annotated
;; point: the cursor point when the annotation was first displayed (perhaps this
;;        could be improved to be the last point moved to on the annotation)
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-defstruct annotation-details rev point)

;; The vc-annotate-mode-hook can't be used because it is run before
;; the vc-annotate-parent-* variables are set.
;;
;; So instead use a advise function for vc-annotate, called before
;; vc-annotate, which stores the arguments on the appropriate stack.
(defun record-annotation-call (file rev &optional display-mode buf move-point-to vc-bk)
  (message "Recording annotation: file %S rev %S" file rev)
  (let ((annotation-stack (gethash file vc-annotate-call-stacks)))
    (push (make-annotation-details :rev rev
                                   :point move-point-to)
          annotation-stack)
    (puthash file annotation-stack vc-annotate-call-stacks)))

(advice-add 'vc-annotate :before #'record-annotation-call)

(defun vc-annotate-previous-annotation ()
  "Go back to showing the annotation of the previous displayed annotation"
  (interactive)
  (when (not (equal major-mode 'vc-annotate-mode))
    (error "Can only be used in vc-annotate-mode"))
  (let ((annotation-stack (gethash vc-annotate-parent-file vc-annotate-call-stacks)))
       (when (< (length annotation-stack) 2)
         (error "No previous vc-annotate calls"))
       ;; The entry at the top of the stack is the current annotation.
       ;; So need to pop two entries to get the previous annotation.
       (let
           ((curr-annotation (pop annotation-stack))
            (prev-annotation (pop annotation-stack)))
         ;; Update the annotation-stack in the hash table after removing the entries.
         ;; The entry for the one we're returning to will be re-added by
         ;; the advise function for vc-annotate.
         (puthash vc-annotate-parent-file annotation-stack vc-annotate-call-stacks)

         (vc-annotate vc-annotate-parent-file
                      (annotation-details-rev prev-annotation)
                      vc-annotate-parent-display-mode
                      (current-buffer)
                      (annotation-details-point prev-annotation)
                      vc-annotate-backend))))
```

Comment: how can I bind `vc-annotate-previous-annotation` to the key `b` during `vc-annotate`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.

```
(defun vc-annotate-revision-next-to-line ()
  "Visit the annotation of the revision after the revision at line.
This is the dual to `vc-annotate-revision-previous-to-line'."
  (interactive)
  (if (not (equal major-mode 'vc-annotate-mode))
  (message "Cannot be invoked outside of a vc annotate buffer")
(let* ((rev-at-line (vc-annotate-extract-revision-at-line))
       (next-rev nil)
       (rev (car rev-at-line))
       (fname (cdr rev-at-line)))
  (if (not rev-at-line)
      (message "Cannot extract revision number from the current line")
    (setq next-rev
      (vc-call-backend vc-annotate-backend 'next-revision
               fname rev))
    (vc-annotate-warp-revision next-rev fname)))))
;; vc-annotate-revision-previous-to-line is bound to "a"; use "e" for symmetry.
(eval-after-load "vc-annotate"
  '(define-key vc-annotate-mode-map "e" 'vc-annotate-revision-next-to-line))
```

Comment: This seems useful in general, but I don't believe it's answering the question.

Comment: I'm not sure this is particularly useful either. `j` followed by `n` should do the same.